# Airflow: Current Task Failure, How To Mark Downstream As Skipped or No Status

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have a DAG where the last task is an `EmailOperator` to send an informational "success" email.  When the previous (previous to EmailOperator) task fails, and is marked as, `State: failed`, the last task (`EmailOperator`) is then shown as yellow in the UI `up_for_retry`, but is marked in the logs as, `State: upstream_failed`.

Why does a task with `upstream_failed` get assigned to `up_for_retry` or at least in this specific case?  Is there way to ensure it is not `up_for_retry` and have it visualized as `skipped` or `no_status`.

Here are my current `default_args` setting...

```
default_args = {
    'owner': '<myname>',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 9, 27),
    'email': ['<myemail>'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    #'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0
    #'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=15)
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure you didn't confuse the colors on UI? from [source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/state.py#L73), `UP_FOR_RETRY: 'gold'` and `UPSTREAM_FAILED: 'orange'`. this is baffling since `up_for_retry` means task is yet to complete (and your DAG will not be marked completed by Airflow if some task is UP_FOR_RETRY). `UPSTREAM_FAILED` on the other hand tells that task couldn't be (and wouldn't be) run because it's parent task(s) have failed as per given [`trigger_rule`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L191)

Comment: @y2k-shubham I have added a screen shot of the Airflow Dag UI to show what I am referencing.  The second to last column is the prime example and looking at the color codes in the link you sent, that could be the case.

Comment: I realized the error in my judgement by assuming that `UP_FOR_RETRY` (color gold) is the same as `UPSTREAM_FAILED` (color orange), even though the state `UPSTREAM_FAILED` is not shown in the "task state key".  This post can be closed if possible.